# Magento 1 sample data files to validate Magento 2 Data Migration Tool?

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool, sample-data

Does anyone know of a repo that contains a downloadable links to the various sample data archives for M1 ? I can find a link for magento-sample-data-1.9.1.0.tgz , but no others.

I'm trying to test using the Magento 2 Data Migration Tool using a known and reproduceable set of data. I've been using a clean install of v1.9.2.2 with the 1.9.1.0 sample data installed, and trying to import to v2.3.5p2 using the v2.3.5 Data Migration tool. And it's chock full of errors and unmapped attributes when I attempt to migrate data. Which seems odd as I would imagine that would be an obvious test case for the M2 tool.

So I'm wondering if the M2 data migration tool is actually functional, if there's a specific issue with that version of M1 or the sample data version,  or just my plain incompetence. Other versions of more recent sample data would help me validate the same issue occurs with more recent v1.9.x versions.

Complete ass-hat move by Adobe removing all references to M1 from their website...

Comment: I think for testing you should be able to use the 1.9.1.0 sample data archive with the last version of M1. Why are you testing with 1.9.2 and not 1.9.4.x

Comment: Because the site I’m migrating from is running a fully patched version of 1.9.2.2